# structuremap automatically look for missing implementations in subdirectory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Is it possible to point StructureMap at a subdirectory containing concrete implementations (one concrete implementation per interface) and get StructureMap to Automatically wire up concrete classes without needing to declare your interfaces in ObjectFactory.Initialize( y=> y.Scan ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible(assuming that you follow some naming convention).

Example:

naming convention for interfaces: IName (IA, IB)

naming convention for interface implementation: Name (A, B)

Above naming convention is known as default convention in SM.

Then you may scan using default convention like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => 
                { x.Scan(
                      scan =>
                      {
                          scan.AssembliesFromPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Impl" ); //location of assemblies with interfaces implementation
                          scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                      }
                    );
                });
```

If you need more complicated rule of mapping then you may implement your own convention.

Here is more information on this subject: http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section8

Here is example solution: https://github.com/st4hoo/StructuremapExample